# Does height difference between beacons results in a more accurate 3D position localisation?

Tags: measurements, trilateration, aerial-triangulation

I'm kinda fresh on the trilateration/triangulation topic.

If you place 4 beacons in each corner of a room at the same height or if you place them on different heights relative to each other will this have an impact on the accuracy of your triangulation/trilateration?

I suppose if you use an error minimizing approach as the Nonlinear least squares it does make a difference as if a closed form algrebraic approach were used, it wouldn't matter?

Answer (score 1):

It makes a difference because real measurements contain error.

If you have four corners of a square, you can minimise error in relation to the plane that the square is in. However this will give you less-good results for measurements normal to that plane (the "up-down" direction for your four corners of a room).

By contrast, placing them at each corner of a triangular pyramid will give you more balanced errors. This is analogous to PDOP / HDOP in a GPS system.

Which makes more sense for your situation depends on how sensitive your system is to the errors in each direction. Also real-world installation considerations often over-ride mathematical ideals.